# Date format by XDO Tag in excel template of Oracle BI Publisher

Tags: sql, excel, rtf, bi-publisher

I am using Excel template in BI Publisher and have added the tag XDO_?FROM_DATE? in one of the columns. I want this to come in the format - DD-MM-YYYY. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Right now it is coming in -2020-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 format

Answer (score 1):

Make another row, and reference the first cell in a formula. Your formula would look something like this since the source data is in `D2`:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(D2,10))
```

Then format the date cell as you want.

Hide the row you don't want to see in the results.

Reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_excel_tmpl.htm#BIPRD2752

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that `We use two columns, one for raw data, and the second one is for format data where we apply excel formula. Then we hide column of raw data'`

Please follow this [Formatting Dates](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_excel_tmpl.htm#exc_form_dates)

There are 6 steps to follow.

However, the format, you can choose full DateTime

```
=--REPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(E8,"T"," "),LEN(E8)-6,6,"")
```

or just date

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(E8,10))
```